# Python Modules are not being recognized by Bash (Cygwin)

Tags: python, bash, cygwin

I'm trying to run a python script in bash (with Cygwin on Windows 10), however it does not recognize modules like Matplotlib. For example, if I want to compile and run a script, I type in `python text_reader.py` and the result is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`. The script works fine in the CMD terminal and in Pycharm, but not in BASH. I believe the issue is that the the path of the python interpreters are different. If so, then how could I make the paths of the interpreters the same?

Answer (score 0):

you need to install it most likely. have you tried.

`pip install matplotlib`

OR

`pip3 install matplotlib`

Comment: It says "requirement already satisfied" in the bash terminal. Matplotlib works in general. It just doesn't work in bash.

Comment: Think it helps to distinguish what you're doing here as. CMD is a windows command line where's bash is a *nix shell. what are you running bash in?

Comment: Initially I ran it in the CMD terminal by writing the bash command. But I also run it in the Cygwin terminal. Both yield the same result for `pip install matplotlib`. `Requirement already satisfied`

Comment: I think the issue is most likely that the python interpreter on Cygwin is different from the python interpreter on PyCharm. `print(sys.path)` yield different results in Pycharm and Cygwin. And most obviously, Python 3.6 is being used on Cygwin, whilst I'm using Python 3.9. And when it says `Requirement already satisfied`, it shows the path where matplotlib is installed which is also along the path where my Python interpreter is.

Comment: Need to provide more details next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I had to change the PATH environment variable to my python interpreter with the following BASH command,

```
$ export PATH="PATH TO PYTHON INTERPRETER"
```

and then I can normally compile a python file using a numpy or matplotlib module with

```
$ python text_reader.py
```

Comment: `numpy` and now also `matplotlib` are available as cygwin packages  https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2021-February/247684.html. To use Cygwin `matplotlib` for graphics you need to have a running  XServer